# Combining templates to be used with backbone js

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, ejs

I'm getting started with backbone js, and I'm interested in combining all of my templates for various parts of my web application into one file and then caching it. I'm looking at _underscore and EJS for templating engines. Anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Hashmap translates nicely for this purpose. But your server side must preprocess the set of html templates into hash map and assign it to global variable. Your models, collection will get the html from hashmap using **keys** then apply json as data

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), which includes a ['text' plugin](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#text) for templates.

You can then use the [r.js optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) to combine all of these (plus JS modules, if you go that route) into a single file.

The optimizer can be run either as part of your build process, or in-process if you're using node.js.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to stusmith's suggestion, you can use [StealJS](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!stealjs) to compile EJS templates(or any js file).

Within your app files you can setup dependencies, such as your templates and other resources:

```
steal('jquery', 'template_a.ejs', 'template_b.ejs', function() {

  //some app code

});
```

Then you can use the steal build tool to combine all your dependencies into one or many minified, concatenated files.